# drawing in canvas using canvas width and height

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw 3 rows of barrels with 4 barrels each row. In order for it to fit all screens I'm using canvas' height and width. this is my code:

```
int width = canvas.getWidth();
int height=canvas.getHeight();
int x = 20, y = 20, count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(BarrelSprite, width*(x/100), height*(y/100), null);
        rect[count] = new Rect( width*(x/100), height*(y/100),  width*(x/100) + BarrelSprite.getWidth(), height*(y/100) + BarrelSprite.getHeight());
        count++;
        x += 20;
    }
y += 20;
x = 20;
```

when I run it all the barrels seems to stack at the top left corner for some reason. I wanted to draw every barrel's X in the first 20% of the screen, 40%,60% etc. same for Y value.

Answer (score 0):

found the mistake, height was int variable and dividing it by 100 making it 0 so I multiply by 0 all the the time hence making all the barrels fit the 0,0 coordinates